# slidetoggle () is not a function?

Tags: jquery

Перестал работать slideToggle(); - slideToggle() is not a function

```js
$(function() {
  $('.office-title').click(function() {
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();

    $(this).parent().siblings().children().next().slideUp();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title 1</h3>
  <div class="office" style="display:none;">sadasd 1</div>
</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title 2</h3>
  <div class="office" style="display:none;">sadasd 2</div>
</div>
<div class="office-row">
  <h3 class="office-title">Title 3</h3>
  <div class="office" style="display:none;">sadasd 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/slidetoggle/

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Код и консоль в студию.